# How does angular recalculate the changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function calculate that takes four parameters and returns the product of them. I had put up a console log in it.

- When I change num_1 for the first time the function calculate is called once.
- When I click num_2 for the first time the function calculate is called once.
- When I change num_2 the function calculate is called thrice.
- When I change num_3 the function is called twice.
- When I change num_4 the function is called twice.
- When I change num_1 again the function is called thrice.

I have put up a log in the console to note the number of function calls. I am beginner in AngularJS. Please explain the why the function is called so many times does it depend upon the other functions `scale_by_2` and `scale_by_4`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

    <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="calculateController as calc">
        <p> Number 1 : <input type="num" min="1" ng-model="calc.num_1"></p>
        <p> Number 2 : <input type="num" min="1" ng-model="calc.num_2"></p>
        <p> Number 2 : <input type="num" min="1" ng-model="calc.num_3"></p>
        <p> Number 4 : <input type="num" min="1" ng-model="calc.num_4"></p>
         {{ calculate(calc.num_1, calc.num_2, calc.num_3, calc.num_4) }}
        <p> Scale by 2 : {{ scale_by_2(calc.num_1, calc.num_2, calc.num_3, calc.num_4) }} </p>
        <p> Scale by 2 : {{ scale_by_4(calc.num_1, calc.num_2, calc.num_3, calc.num_4) }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

     app.controller('calculateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.num_1 = 1;
     $scope.num_2 = 1;
     $scope.num_3 = 1;

     $scope.calculate =  function(num_1, num_2,num_3,num_4) {
         $scope.product = num_1 * num_3 * num_4 ;
         console.log(num_1);
         return num_1 * num_2;
     }

     $scope.scale_by_2 =  function(num_1, num_2,num_3,num_4) {
         num = $scope.product;
         return num * 2;
     }

     $scope.scale_by_4 =  function(num_1, num_2,num_3,num_4) {
         num = $scope.product;
         return num * 4;
     }
     }]);
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular updates the values that you see on the front-end by running through its digest cycle. During the digest cycle, functions called in your view(s) may be called multiple times, usually until Angular is certain that your values have settled.

From [Angular's docs on `$digest()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest):

> Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children.
>   Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the $digest() keeps
>   calling the watchers until no more listeners are firing. This means
>   that it is possible to get into an infinite loop. This function will
>   throw 'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.' if the number of iterations
>   exceeds 10.

It's hard to explain why Angular calls your methods *exactly that many times* without digging deep into the digest cycle of your example, but it's definitely to be expected. This is why it's important to avoid calling too many functions in your view like that - every time the view changes, all of them will be processed at least once.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I display the product of two numbers when the numbers change?

Comment: For simple calculations, keep doing what you're doing - it's the easiest, cleanest way. For more complex calculations (calculations that would result in a noticeable delay if they run multiple times), you may wish to explore alternatives, such as using `$scope.$watch()` on the values, or using a button that triggers the calculation function when the user is ready.

Comment: Thanks. I will check on those. But using the button click options will defeat the data binding concepts right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use a simple variable in the view (`{{ calculationResult }}`) which is then updated when the button is clicked (`ng-click="updateCalculationResult()"`). The concept of data binding does not mean that everything has to be instant/dynamic, it depends on your particular use case.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. For the data/result that has to be dynamic or instant is function call from view the only way in angular?

Comment: Either a function call in the view, or a `$scope.$watch()` in your controller. The watch logic would then update a variable which is shown in the view. Both options should appear dynamic/instantaneous, although I'm not sure which one would result in less calls (both might be the same).